# Golang OOP information hiding practice

Tags: oop, go, struct

What can I do with Go struct to hide information? Go struct member is visible to all. How to hide a member in a package?

Comment: You can make them private by making them lowercase.

Comment: What squiguy said. The same goes for encoding to other formats (JSON, XML etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go is not an Object oriented language. But it encapsulates things at the package level.

According to [GoLang specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers);-

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case
>      letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field
>      name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

If you don't wants to make your struct variables public do not export them. use lowercase to create variables in a struct type.
Unexported struct fields are only accessible to same package.

```
// unexported struct
type person struct {
    name string // unexported fields can be used only in the same package
    age  int
}
```

Only package level granularity is allowed in Go. One can declare struct in different package which can be used in those files wherever it is required

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that you still have to make your structs (not just the constructors for those structs) public if they will be passed back into a function in the package.  Otherwise it's impossible to mock them or create interfaces.  I don't think golang truly provides information hiding, in this sense.  It's more like python where "we're all adults" but it has types for performance.  I can't say I'm a fan, but I still have to code in it to get paid.